# How can one click a button on different domain web page using Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tried using iframes as shown below but it's not working.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
if (y.document)y = y.document;
//the code clicking the button
}
</script>
```

Is there a way I can trigger a button click on a web page running on a different domain? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

mate, answer is no, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the modern browser block the Javascript execution on iframe by parent window... This is the security issue

Answer (score 0):

JS iFrame execution is mainly blocked in modern browser due to security issues

Answer (score 0):

You can't access 3rd party website DOM using javascript. Almost all browsers prevents this due to security reasons. Consider internet banking sites for example, if it is possible to access the DOM of an internet banking site using iframe and javascript, it is very easy to steal the username and password.